# Quero saber como ler um domDocument com um xml dentro

Tags: php, xml

Atualmente o projeto utilizando um print_r na variável `xml` e retorna isso:

> `SimpleXMLElement Object ( [cidade] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [nome] => ARACAJU [estado] => SE ) [bairros] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [bairro] => Array ( [0] => 18 DO FORTE [1] => AEROPORTO [2] => ARUANA [3] => ATALAIA [4] => CASTELO BRANCO [5] => CENTRO [6] => CIRURGIA [7] => CORO DO MEIO [8] => COROA DO MEIO [9] => FAROLâNDIA [10] => GETúLIO VARGAS [11] => GRAGERU [12] => INáCIO BARBOSA [13] => JABOTIANA [14] => JARDINS [15] => LUZIA [16] => PONTO NOVO [17] => SALGADO FILHO [18] => SANTA MARIA [19] => SANTO ANTôNIO [20] => SUíSSA [21] => SãO CONRADO [22] => TREZE DE JULHO ) ) ) )`

Gostaria de saber como exibir apenas os bairros ou apenas as cidades

Comment: poste o xml também!

Comment: De uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7778950/9643815), pra converter o SimpleXmlElement pra um array, depois é só acessar pelo indice `cidade` ou `bairros`.